# In Stata, how can I change color of the coefplot's gridlines?

Tags: graph, stata

I'm trying to change the color of gridlines in a Stata's graph. The usual method works fine in builtin graphs

```
sysuse auto
hist mpg, ylabel(, grid glcolor(green))
```

However, it fails when I try to do the same with `coefplot` graph where the grid has default blueish color:

```
reg price mpg headroom trunk length turn
coefplot, drop(_cons) xline(0) ylabel(, grid glcolor(green))
```

Any ideas how to change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reg price mpg headroom trunk length turn
coefplot, drop(_cons) xline(0) grid( glcolor(green))
```

ps: I only read the help of the command `coefplot`, where it is clearly explained; in general the command `help` provides many answers.

Comment: Thanks. Did the job.